# Import current UI into sketchflow

Tags: prototyping, sketchflow

I need prototype the UI for next gen of my ASP.Net app. I'd like to use a tool like Sketchflow to mock of the new screens and updates to the currents screens.

Can I import my current UI into Sketchflow? Is there another prototyping tool that does allow importing existing UIs?

Comment: I've gone from C# to SketchFlow before, but only did my UserControls... not the entire application.

Comment: What did you import, an ascx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen shots are good (this is how Sketch Flow imports PowerPoint presentations), but I guarantee your audience will focus too much on the current look if it is not "*Sketchy*".

A good trick for existing layouts is to cut/paste* an image/screen-shot into a Sketchflow page, then trace over it using standard sketchflow rectanges, buttons, pencil tool etc.
[image]

When you are done, remove (or simply hide) the reference image. The end result has the rough layout and functionality, but looks like a prototype.

[image]

*Tip: You can paste an image straight from the clipboard into Expression Blend pages if you use a paint package (Paint.Net is great for this). The Pencil sketch effect option in Paint.Net (below) also helps convert existing stuff into a more *Sketchy* look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in import command that will do this. It also depends on your goals, if you just want a starting point, screenshots might be the most useful. You could create the basic structure in SketchFlow and paste in screen shots, and start from there.